# Adding FCM to vue PWA

Tags: firebase, vue.js, notifications

I am trying to add Firebase Massaging to my VueJS PWA app, but I am getting the following error:

> @ ./src/main.js 6:0-28 28:13-16  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.7:8080/sockjs-node
>   (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

**manifest.json in the Public folder looks like :**

```
   "start_url": ".",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#000000",
    "theme_color": "#210499",
    "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
```

**firebase-messaging-sw.js in the public folder looks like :**

```
   importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
   importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

   var config = {
       messagingSenderId: "452219633362"
   };
   firebase.initializeApp(config);

   let messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

**App.vue file Looks like :**

```
created() {
    var config = {
      apiKey: "My apiKey",
      authDomain: "My firebase domain",
      databaseURL: "database URL",
      projectId: "Project ID",
      storageBucket: "storage Bucket",
      messagingSenderId: "Sender id "
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    let messaging = firebase.messaging();

   messaging
      .requestPermission()
      .then(() => firebase.messaging().getToken())
      .then(token => {
        console.log(token); // Receiver Token to use in the notification
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
      });

    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      // ...
    });
  }
```

main.js looks like :

```
   import Vue from "vue";
    import App from "./App.vue";
    import firebase from "firebase";
    import "../public/firebase-messaging-sw"

    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
     var config = {
          apiKey: "My apiKey",
          authDomain: "My firebase domain",
          databaseURL: "database URL",
          projectId: "Project ID",
          storageBucket: "storage Bucket",
          messagingSenderId: "Sender id "
    };
     firebase.initializeApp(config);

    Vue.prototype.$messaging = firebase.messaging()

    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
      .then((registration) => {
        Vue.prototype.$messaging.useServiceWorker(registration)
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
     })
    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
```

I cannot point out what I did wrong. I did use Vue-Cli version 3. Can someone help me with this error?